# How can I return if error - C

Tags: c, return

Basically I have this data structure:

```
typedef struct Data {
    char *str;
    int n;
} TData, *AData;
```

Where I want to allocate space for `str` using malloc (in that variable I am putting a string that I read from a file which, honestly, it's not that important considering the topic of my question). Therefore, I created a function `TData InitData(const char *file_name)`:

```
TData InitData(const char *file_name) {
    TData data;

    data.str = malloc(1024);
    if (!data.str) {
        printf("Allocation error!\n");
        // I have no idea what to return here in order to exit the function.
        return (...);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Now, in my 'main()' function, I would make the call something like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    TData data;
    if(!(data = ReadExpression(argv[1]))) {
        return 1;
    }
    // I do something with my data and the program ends.
    return 0;
}
```

How can I make the return statement valid in the `InitData` function?

I know that the other way, and probably the recommended way is either to send `TData data` from `main` to `InitData` as a parameter of type `AData` and change the type of the function to `int` (would result into something like: `int InitData(const char *file_name, AData data)`) or to simply use `AData`.

Comment: `return NULL;` perhaps? Like malloc does. You'll need to make data a pointer to `*Tdata` then of course.

Comment: Won't work because the function is `TData` type. In order to return 'NULL' it has to be `void *` or pointer.

Comment: You define the semantics of your own structures yourself. So, what's the sentinel-value, or is there none? I would guess `(TData){0, 0}`. Also, consider defining your structure as `typedef struct data{size_t len;char data[]} data;`, and always allocating it on the heap. Anyway, hiding the use of poiners behind typedefs is dangerous.

Comment: @Deduplicator Hmm, I undertand what you mean and I think that would be the best solution.

Comment: @Deduplicator T `int n` in the struct stands for something else, it's not used for the data size. However can you give me more info about 'always allocating it on the heap'. Last, but not least, I can not agree more with you about hiding pointers in typedefs, however that's the practice being thought at my university.

Comment: @DragosRizescu That's what I point out in the second sentence: you'll need to return a pointer instead. That may also help better in remembering that you'll need to free your `data.str` at the end.

Comment: My example structure uses an incomplete array type at the end, so the string is saved directly following the other struct members. Somehow, the neccessary space has to be reserved... Search for the struct hack (pre-C99) and incomplete types for later standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As a rule of thumb, always pass structs as pointer parameters and not by value.
- As a rule of thumb, when writing complex functions, reserve the return value for errors.

So in your case, rewrite the function as:

```
bool InitData (TData* data, const char *file_name);
```

where the bool can be replaced by an enum for more detailed error codes. Right now the function result is only "ok" or "error".

Answer (score 1):

C does not have an inbuilt multiple value return, so usually what you do is

```
int InitData(const char *file_name, TData *returnedData) { ... }
```

The return value of InitData is then the error/success flag and the `TData` structure is returned via the pointer.

Comment: Thought to use that as well, was the first thought right after I realised that I can't signal an error return. Also said in the question the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

i did not do much in `C` but many functions are like this:

```
int foo(intargs, outargs);
```

the thing behind this is that you allocate the object and pass it as a reference to be filled inside the function.

the return value of the function will be an `enum` or something like this to be compared to determine what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I love the way MicroVirus suggested. Accepting the data as a parameter also be used for multithreaded code safety. Moreover, you can return the result of operation in order to check in the calling code. Your TData is not a pointer so you can not set it to NULL, which is a one way of telling an invalid case I think. However, there is another problem here! TData data in InitData is a local variable and should be copied when the function returns. It is not a good practice for performance issues I think. I suggest, accept the object as a parameter (as a pointer for example) return the result of the function to the calling code and check that for the validity of the data. You can set data NULL or not, but when you return a result value this makes everything cleae without checking the data object itself.

Comment: An optimising compiler should be able to omit copying the object, and having it constructed on the stack in-place, so just as efficient as a pointer.

Comment: If you are talking about ROV (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), yes you are right, but I am not sure whether this is the case for C.

Comment: I admit, I assumed C would have a similar optimisation, but a quick Google search finds nothing; it's strewn with C++ related articles. So, maybe I was wrong, and C does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `data` as normal, but change your code in `main()` to read:

```
data = ReadExpression(argv[1]);
if ( !data.str ) {
    return 1;
}
```

You can't return a scalar value in place of a `struct`, and your question suggests you already know you can use a pointer but are choosing not to, so this is the simplest alternative way.

Comment: This is bad program design. If the caller knows about the members of the struct, why couldn't the caller do the allocation to begin with? You should strive to use private encapsulation.

Comment: @Lundin: It's not my program. The OP is asking how to do it this way. As for "why couldn't the caller do the allocation to begin with", because there are more uses for functions other than encapsulation. Moving the allocation to a separate function can make `main()` more readable, and avoids duplication if the same operation needs to be performed somewhere else, or more than once in `main()`.

Comment: And he is doing some fumbling attempts towards proper OO design, by encapsulating the malloc inside a code module that knows what TData is. Removing detailed checks away from the code module breaks the encapsulation completely and isn't helping him to learn OO program design.

Comment: That's pure speculation on your part, and such an approach would fail to answer the OP's question. Apart from anything else, `main()` in this short, contrived example could be a proxy for a constructor function initializing a file-scope static variable in a separate module, for all you know.

Comment: Well... either you know about OO design or you don't. If you don't, your program design will be crap no matter what you do. And then all questions like this one are pointless.

Comment: This is C. Sometimes a `struct` is just a `struct`, a data record, a collection of loosely-related data that you neither want nor ought to "encapsulate" as part of some "OO design". Claiming that a program must be "crap" if its author doesn't use "proper OO design" is just odd.

Comment: I can tell you from experience that there exist very few good C programs in the world that do not have some kind of OO design. OO in this C context essentially means ADTs with private encapsulation and "member functions". The very few good ones that didn't have such a design were all small: typically less than 1000 LOC, close to the hardware, some 8-bit embedded system etc. In all other cases, programs written without an OO approach are pretty much exclusively crap. At least that's my conclusion after spending a significant part of the past 15 years reading other people's C code.

Comment: The problem is that standard functions such as `gmtime()` and `localtime()`, not to mention Unix functions such as `readdir()`, `getaddrinfo()` and a host of others, return pointers to structures which you don't own and which you did not allocate, and not only encourage you to access the members directly, but actually compel you to do so. You are at liberty to dismiss these interfaces and all programs that use them as "crap" if you want to, but I suspect this would be a minority view, regardless of to which conclusions your experience might have led you.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a flag in the Data-struct set depending on the `if (!data.str)` result, and always return `data`.
Then check the flag whenever you want to know what happened.

Just to clarify:
You could write something like this, or similar:

```
`typedef struct Data 
{
    char *str;
    int n;
    char myflag;
    const char *file_name;
} TData, *AData;`

`void InitData(TData *data) 
{
    data.str = malloc(1024);
    if (!data.str) 
    {
        printf("Allocation error!\n");
        myflag=0;
    }
    else
    {
        myflag=1;
    }
    return data;
}`
```

But see the comments also. Just wanted to give another perspective.

Comment: The memory allocation error isn't in the slightest related to the data of the struct, so it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Well, you decide for yourself if it has something to do with the data - either the data is only the original data OR it is the original data plus some sort of allocation info. Both alternatives are valid.

Comment: However if you don't need the allocation data afterwards, you should probably not save it around in the struct. I don't know what it will be used for so...